# Linq c# how to get value in between?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 4.0 and I have the following columns in a datatable:

```
 Points Title
 180    Senior Engineer
 100    Junior Engineer
 220    Project Manager
 270    Senior Project Manger
```

Now I have one UserID at `int UserID = 20` and he has a total of *150* points, so he must have the title *Junior Engineer*. I have another with `UserID = 23` which has a total of *200* points so he must have the title *Senior engineer*. 
How do I get a `Title` by passing a `UserID`? I want to use C# for this.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: not clear what db struture you have

Comment: Why do the guy with 180 points have title "Senior Engineer" in your overview if the threshold is 200?

Comment: How can one obtain `Points` having a `UserId`?

Comment: I don't understand the rule here. Why must he have a title of senior engineer? Is the point value the *maximum* value he's allowed to have as a senior, or is it the *required* value that he must have to be a senior? If the latter then he should be a Junior Engineer?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. How is that table from your question related to a users ID? Are these values limits of experience, meaning that for a user given by an UUID with a set of poitns you want to know its level of experience?

Comment: sounds a bit like you could use the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern

Comment: so user id doesn't have any importance here. Point associated with user id does matter for this functionality. Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is often the best; I think you want simply calculate the difference between a users points and the points needed for a given level.

So you can do this:

```
var points = myUser.Points;
var title = points >= 270 ? "Senior Project Manger" :
        points >= 220 ? "Project Manager" :
        points >= 180 ? "Senior Engineer" :
        "Junior Engineer";
```

The following LINQ may also wotk:

```
var points = 200;
var myTable = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 270, "Senior Project Manger" },
    { 220, "Project Manager" },
    { 180, "Senior Engineer" }, 
    { 100, "Junior Engineer" }};

var max = myTable.Select(x => points - x.Key).OrderBy(x => x).First(x => x > 0);
var level = myTable.Single(x => points - x.Key == max);
```

This should return `"Senior Engineer"`

This assumes there is no user having less then 100 points.

Answer (score 2):

It is bit unclear, assuming that you have a user with some points, you could do something like this to get title for him/her by lookup.

```
UserPoints = 185;
var rank = RankPoints.OrderBy(p=>p.Points)
                     .FirstOrDefault(x => x >= UserPoints);

if(rank != null)
{
   title = rank.Title; // this is your title
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if UserPoints is greater than max (270, in this case)

Comment: Just use .FirstOrDefault(x => x >= UserPoints) after ordering? Skipwhile not needed.

Comment: @PMBjornerud thanks for that, updated it.

Comment: @Szeki That's correct, but looks like that's what OP wants. _A person with 150 points will have title Juniner Engineer_,  If want's op can assign _default_ title.